# Why is my sql count printing alphabetical text?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

```
    $users = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(votes.id) FROM users INNER JOIN votes
                                ON users.id=votes.recipientuserid WHERE votes.datenumber >='2014' ");

    while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users)){
        $count = $user[COUNT(votes.id)];
    }
```

In phpmyadmin the query count displays a number. The value of $count is not a number but the users.username value. Why?

Comment: That would be `$user['COUNT(votes.id)']`. But you should use an alias in your query: `SELECT *, COUNT(votes.id) as cnt FROM users....` and then `$count = $user['cnt'];`

Comment: @Bart Not if I'm selecting users, not votes.

Comment: Why do I need an alias? @VolkerK

Comment: To make it more readable and robust. But it will probably work with `$user['COUNT(votes.id)']` <- just don't forget to put the single quotes in there. Otherwise php will concat the two undefined constants `votes` and `id` -> `count('votesid')` -> 1 -> `$user[1]` and that's probably a field you've selected via *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want is to modify your query by adding a field name to count so that you can access it as any other field in the results:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(votes.id) as nbvotes FROM users ...
```

And the from php once you have the results, you can access it this way

```
$row['nbvotes']
```

where $row is the variable containing the record returned from mysql. Do not forget the appostrophes.

Cheers

Comment: Why do I have to use the as feature? What does it do and why do I need it?

Comment: @desbest: Assign an *alias* to the expression in the SELECT list to *explicitly* specify the name of the column in the result set. It may not be strictly necessary to assign an alias, but it's a common pattern. I think it makes the code more readable, it follows the pattern you use for other columns **`= $user['mycount'];`**. Consider an example of a more elaborate expression in the SELECT list, e.g. `SUM(IF((c.id MOD 10) > 4), 1, 0)` and you'll see why assigning an alias to an expression is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$users = mysql_query("SELECT  COUNT(votes.id) as count FROM users INNER JOIN votes
                                ON users.id=votes.recipientuserid WHERE votes.datenumber >='2014' ");

    while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users)){
        $count = $user['count'];
    }
```